# AngularJs image base 64 replace invalid character

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to output a base64 image in angular. I got a base64 string from external service and I need to output an image. The problem is that the string returned has invalid character as "_". If I try to replace those characters I cannot render the image.

Fiddle : http://jsbin.com/AYIQUhi/2/edit

I've tested in coldfusion and the image is rendered perfectly. So the problem should be angular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your base64 string not only has "_" as invalid char, but other characters as well. Try converting your base64 image (after the `replace(/_/g, '/')`) into a binary file with a tool as http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html to check it.